# Patch existing kernel module with dkms

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dkms

Creating a debian package with a kernel module seems fairly easy as described [here](http://www.xkyle.com/building-linux-packages-for-kernel-drivers/) and elsewhere. I want to update an existing module with [a patch](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/scripts/realsense-camera-formats.patch). How would I go about this? I don't really have a source tarball to unpack, but rather I would use the module source for whatever kernel version dkms is building for.

For example let's say I have kernel version 1.2.3 installed, then I would like to build the kernelmodule uvcvideo with version 1.2.3 of the sources, with the addition of a patch. Do I get the sources before I create the dkms .deb package, or do I fetch them during build somehow?

Does the question make sense? How to do it?

Comment: I am unsure that I get you problem correctly, but you may use `PATCH` directive in you `dkms.conf` file for apply patches for module sources before build them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the problem is I don't know how or when to get the correct version of the sources.

Answer (score 2):

DKMS was created to add drivers that are not already in the kernel. This is not your case here.

So I see 2 options:

- You can patch the kernel, where you will find the sources of your module
- You can blacklist the kernel module, get the sources from kernel, rename and patch the module, and add the new module with DKMS

Comment: Could you please describe how you rename a kernel module? Where it should be re-written?